# Where can I get big collections of images for my machine learning projects?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Let's say I'm trying to build a Neural Network that can differentiate between a dog and a cat. Where can I find large collections of images of e.g. cats and dogs? I don't want to use any pre-trained models such as MobileNet for my neural network. Any website suggestions where I can e.g. download a .zip file containing like a 100 images of cats and dogs would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) or [Google Dataset Search](https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been searching for methods from web scraping to other zip collections, but I couldn't find any